# How to subset a large igraph to just one node and its connected nodes using R?

Tags: r, igraph

I have a very large igraph (called g) in R.

I am just interested in one node (NodeA) plus whatever nodes are directly connected to NodeA.  I want to end up with a very simple graph like the picture below.

I have tried subgraph(g, "nodeA") but I just end up with NodeA all by itself.

I think I need to subset the edges of graph g to those that connect to nodeA then use subgraph.edges().  I can't figure out how to subset the edges based on what nodes they are connected to...

[image: NodeA and two directly connected nodes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `neighbors()`

```
# Example graph
g1 <- graph_from_literal(1:2:3---3:4:5)

# Let's take a look at it
plot(g1)
```

[image]

```
# Say we are interested in the subgraph consisting of vertex 1 and all
# other vertices it is connected to

g2 <- induced_subgraph(g1, c(1, neighbors(g1,1)))
plot(g2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  This method, (and thelatemail's method of making the ego graph below) sub-setted to the neighbour nodes. I found the neighbor method easier to understand though the make_ego_graph method has more flexibility.  I also wanted to get rid of the edges between neighbours (eg between 3-4 and 3-5).  To do this I ended up using the neighbour method above and then the delete_edges method. First find of node of interest's name then...
not_node_indices <-which(E(n)$start!=node_name)
not_joined_edges <- E(n)[not_node_indices]
n <-delete_edges(n, not_joined_edges)

Answer (score 0):

`?make_ego_graph` should do it if `order=1`:

```
g <- make_graph(c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6), directed = FALSE)
V(g)$name <- letters[1:6]
g
#IGRAPH  UN-- 6 4 -- 
#+ attr: name (v/c)
#+ edges from 657f0a0 (vertex names):
#[1] a--b b--c c--d e--f

make_ego_graph(g, order=1, nodes=2)
#[[1]]
#IGRAPH UN-- 3 2 -- 
#+ attr: name (v/c)
#+ edges from 69681da (vertex names):
#[1] a--b b--c
```